# Graphql query for local state with an array in Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm setting a property in Apollo on the server and need to query it on the client.

I'm setting the local state state to be ( simplified code to make it readable ):

```
const Navigation = {
  __typename: 'Navigation',
  Links     : [
    {__typename: 'Link', to: '/test-layout-page', text: 'Go to Home'},
    {__typename: 'Link', to: '/test-layout-page', text: 'Go to Page'},
    {__typename: 'Link', to: '/test-layout-article', text: 'Go to Article'},
  ],
};

  const staticContent =  {
    Navigation: Navigation
  }

  const stateLink = withClientState({
    cache,
    defaults: {
        staticContent
      },
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, link]),
    cache,
    ssrMode: ssr,
    connectToDevTools: !ssr && !prod,
  });
```

then on the client I have the query:

```
const GET_STATE = gql`
  {
    renderType @client,
    path @client,
    staticContent @client {
      Navigation {
        Links
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The error I get is with `Links`:

> Error: Missing selection set for object of type Link returned for
>   query field Links

I need the gql query to return all items in the array, I tried to specify fields,

```
const GET_STATE = gql`
  {
    renderType @client,
    path @client,
    staticContent @client {
      Navigation {
        Links {
          text,
          to
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

but I get

> Error: Network error: Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the graphql query. The correct query is:

```
const GET_STATE = gql`
  {
    renderType @client,
    path @client,
    staticContent @client {
      Navigation @client {
        Links @client {
          to,
          text
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```